# vertically center div when body height: 100% without absolute pos

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have this to fill the window:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;}
```

then a container also set to height: 100%, how do I vertically center a div with an image without specifying and set height in pixels and ***without*** using absolute positioning? Using padding-top: 50%; padding-bottom 50%; isn't working - seems to shift the div depending on device site or browser window.

Comment: Does margin: 0 auto; do anything for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `display:table` and `display:table-cell`:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    display: table
}

body>div {
    display: table-cell; 
    text-align: center; /* horizontal */
    vertical-align: middle; /* vertical */
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://paw.princeton.edu/issues/2012/07/11/pages/6994/C-beer.jpg" />
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/2XxCS/3/)

More on [display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) .

Answer (score 4):

today, `display:table` and `table-cell` make it easy, you can have tags to react as a `<table>` would.
basicly :

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
html {
    display: table;
}
body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

whatever will be in body will be vertical-align in the middle.
for text a small box , use text-align on body or margin : auto.
you can transfer display to body and div instead html and body.