# How to center text top/bottom when height 100% & display inline-block?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have responsive panels. I've tried a ton of things to get the text to be vertically centered, but I can't get it to work with what I have using `twitter-bootstrap`.

```css
    *,

    *:before,

    *:after {

      box-sizing: border-box;

    }

    body {

      margin: 0

    }

    .testing-here {

      font-size: 0;

    }

    .panel-default {

      box-sizing: border-box;

      position: relative;

      width: 50%;

      padding-bottom: 40%;

      overflow: hidden;

      background-color: #446CB3;

      display: inline-block;

    }

    .panel-body {

      color: white;

      width: 100%;

      height: 100%;

      text-align: center;

      position: absolute;

      font-size: 16px;

      display: table-cell;

      vertical-align: middle;

    }
```

```html
<div class="testing-here">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Basic panel example show me full page & resize window
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Basic panel example font-size kept in between 16 and 50px max
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Basic panel example
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Basic panel example
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Questions I looked into:**

- [vertically center div when body height: 100% without absolute pos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241800/vertically-center-div-when-body-height-100-without-absolute-pos)
- [Vertical alignment of elements in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div?rq=1)
- [Vertically align text in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div?rq=1)

Comment: you have defined display:table-cell in panel-body but not defined display:table in the parent so you may try that

Comment: Yea that doesn't work either @DhavalChheda

Comment: have you tried using flexbox because that will resolve the issue

Comment: No I'm unfamiliar with flexbox @DhavalChheda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Flexbox: This is the working example of vertically and horizontally centering with flexbox.

**Working example**

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
.testing-here {
  font-size: 0;
}
.panel-default {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #446CB3;
  display: inline-block;
}

.panel-body {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue, the text would sit at the bottom. Changing the flex direction to column fixed it.

Comment: Can you please add example CSS also?

Comment: I had the same problem, but it was with React Native actually. I put Text inside of one View nested within another View whose height was 100%. On the nested View I put the following styling: `width: '100%', height: '100%', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center` (flex direction is `column` by default in RN. Then my text centered vertically.